# css transition height 0 to 100(- 80px) not smooth in Safari and on mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Here's live [demo](http://andriikoval.com/r-kafija/). Please check links "Rio 2016" and "Pokemon GO". This links collapsed 2 sections at top.

I have this jquery script witch just toggle `active` class.

```
$('.header-themes a').click(function(e) {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')), $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.removeClass('active');
            $('.header-themes a').removeClass('active');
        });

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $target.addClass('active');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

By default sections at top have `height: 0;` and `active` class add them `height: calc(100% - 80px)`.

Any suggestions how make it smoother?

Comment: Animating height is always expensive, as the layout needs to be recalculated on each frame. For smoothness you would need to rethink the entire approach using `transform: translate(x, y)`.

Comment: I don't think you're having smoothness issues per se. It is more of a visual effect caused by the text moving and stopping, that makes the slide up look clumsy. Try keeping the text in it's original place and tell me if you still feel it's not smooth enough.